# How to efficiently duplicate geometry and data without bpy.ops?

Tags: python, operator

Operators from bpy.ops are reputedly very slow and to be avoided where possible, so how would I go about duplicating geometry and data like uv maps and vertex groups without using bpy.ops?

The intention would be to duplicate geometry associated to a mesh as opposed to duplicating the mesh data.